# scrollTo class not working

Tags: javascript, html

need your help on `scrollTo` function, which is not working currently (doesn't do anything on click)

**Js:**

```
$('#Sb').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('.screen_3').scrollIntoView();
});
```

**HTML (nav):**

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="Sb" href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Our works</a></li>
</ul>
```

**HTML (body):**

```
<section id="container" class="screen_3">
      <p class="text_1">Our Services</p>
      ...
</section>
```

nothing happens when you click the link [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/v79r8oe0/16/)

Comment: You appear to be missing the ID selector prefix. It should be `$('#Sb').click(...`

Comment: @Phil still same

Comment: Really, your question still looks the same

Comment: Do you have jQuery installed? Are there any errors in your console? Have you tried any debugging at all?

Comment: @yahoo5000 I think you need a lot practice my friend, donno i should answer this or not, but(a hint), by clicking on `#Sb` you expect the scroller goes in every `.screen_3` locations?!! Use `#container` instead

Comment: Also, you can simply use `document.querySelector('.screen_3').scrollIntoView()`

Comment: @ColinCline that's not correct. `document.querySelector` only returns one element; the first that matches the selector

Comment: @Phil My bad i thought i saw queryselectorAll, thx for correction.

Comment: @Phil scrollIntoView() same result as before

Comment: Your click handler is defined incorrectly. Assuming you do actually have jQuery installed, it should be `$('#Sb').click(function() { ... })`. All you're doing is assigning a `click` property to the jQuery object. Time to start reading the docs more closely ~ https://api.jquery.com/click/. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: @Phil jquery is installed i put a snippet with my index page , and some styling also i tried all methods witch you told and i found on google all it doent its just refresh page when click

Comment: You'll need to cancel the default click event action (but for the `<a>` element, not the `<li>`)

Comment: @Phil i did and its still same , i gave <a> sb id and then cash him using $(this).preventDefault();

Comment: Its wrong to cash event, just use `e.preventDefault();` but you have to pass it into your function like my answer below `.on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This:

```
$('#Sb>a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector(".screen_3").offsetTop);
});
```

if you want to add id in your `a` tag instead `li` use code below:

```
$('#Sb').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector(".screen_3").offsetTop);
});
```

and read this please
[Jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/)
[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v79r8oe0/17/)

Comment: $('#Sb').on('click', function() {
    window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector(".screen_3").offsetTop);
} thats how it should be and its notworking

Comment: error? right click on your browser window (middle of the page) and click on "inspect", then go to "console" tab write back what you see as an error.

Comment: i havent got any errors witch ever way i was doing

Comment: FYI, you'll need to catch the click event on the `<a>`, not the `<li>` in order to prevent the default event action

Comment: @Phil +1 he bind event on `li` not on anchor and i missed it, ty

Comment: I tried both ways , now i have id on <a > and i also chage $this to e still same , i can tell that prevent default is not working as i set href adrress to # and after i click on it it sets me # in url tab

Comment: @yahoo5000 Code had no problem, check jsfiddle that i added to my answer. Code works fine. Including libraries maybe broke your code and page

Comment: e.stopPropagation(); seems to helped